# Laravel foreach "where" with eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have certain fields and data values which cannot be hardcoded into the query. I'm trying to get something like this:

```
return Listing::where('id', $id)
            ->where(function($query) use ($input) {
                 ->where('field_1', 'foo_1')
                 ->where('field_2', 'foo_2')
                 ->where('field_3', 'foo_3') 
            }
            ->get();
```

**Here's what I have **

```
    return Listing::where('id', $id)
        ->where(function($query) use ($input) {
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
                $i++;
                // ->where('field_1', red_1); // Desired output
                ->where("where(field_{$i},".$value."_1)");
                // $query = $query."where(field_{$i},".$value."_1)"."<br>";
                // return $query prints out the following
                /*
                    field_1 red_1,
                    field_2 foo_1,
                    field_3 bar_3
                */
            }
        })
        ->get();
```

Comment: it's php... you can't to write `->where` from an air. Should be object here.

Comment: can you please show me a short example of how I could do this? Thank you

Comment: For example: `$query->where($field, $value);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$listing = Listing::where('id', $id);
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
     $i++;
     // ->where('field_1', red_1); // Desired output
     $listing->where("where(field_{$i},".$value."_1)");
}
$results = $listing->get();
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

```
$query = Listing::where('id', $id);
$i = 0;
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
     $i++;
     $query->where('field_'.$i,$value.'_'.$i);
}
return $query->get();
```

One you're not chaining correctly and two you are mis-using the querybuilder closure. If you want to execute logic like a loop then you have to break down the query. Furthermore using a where closure is like writing a parenthesis around your where conditions.

Something like:

```
  $query->where('bacon', $foo)
  $query->where(function ($query) use ($bar, $baz){
       $query->where('apple', $bar);
       $query->orWhere('orange', $baz)
  });
```

Would roughly translate to:

```
  WHERE bacon = $foo AND (apple = $bar OR orange = $baz)
```